# The apply rule in proof by cases

Tags: coq

I entered the following attempted proof into CoqIde

```
Theorem choice_reverse : (P -> R) /\ (Q -> R)->((P \/ Q) -> R).
Proof.
intros H [h' |h''].
destruct H as [PthenR QthenR].
apply PthenR.
assumption.
apply QthenR.
Qed.
```

The line `apply QthenR` triggers the error `The reference QthenR was not found in the current environment`. What is going wrong here?

I thought `apply PthenR` would extract the implication `P -> R` and then `assumption.` in the next line fetches `h'`.

Why then does `apply QthenR` not do the same thing, extracting the implication `Q -> R`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tactic `intros H [h' |h''].`generated two subgoals.
The `destruct` operates only in the first subgoal.
Thus `PthenR`and `QthenR` are unknown in the second subgoal.

The following script works:

```
Theorem choice_reverse (P Q R: Prop) : (P -> R) /\ (Q -> R)->((P \/ Q) -> R).
Proof.
intros H [h' |h'']; destruct H as [PthenR QthenR].
- apply PthenR; assumption.
- apply QthenR; assumption. 
Qed.
```

Comment: This solution depends on using the `;` in the first line of the proof. Once we move `destruct H as [PthenR QthenR]` to the next line it produces the error `The reference QthenR was not found
in the current environment.` I'm not sure why this might be, but I will have to experiment a bit. :)

Comment: It’s just that `tac1 ; tac2` applies `tac2` to each subgoal generated by `tac1` .   You can get a precise look at the subgoal structure of a proof by using bullets `-’, `+`, …, and the `Show` command.

Comment: You may eliminate the conjunction just once, befoe the disjunction: 
`intros [PthenR QthenTR] [h' | h'']; auto. `

Answer (score 1):

One way to make this work is to add the same `defstruct` statement before the second `apply`.

Comment: Why does that work? In other words, why is it necessary to type it twice?

Comment: See Pierre Castéran's good explanation above.